# Constant dummy variable multiplied into linear multiple regression model

Tags: multiple-regression

I have been running a multiple linear regression to determine the weightings given to certain sports statistics in a player's fantasy sports score.

This part I have no problem with and is within my knowledge. However, although there is a linear relationship between the fantasy score and each given statistic, what also happens is that the sum of all players' fantasy scores in a match is scaled up or down to a set value. This is so that in games where fewer statistics are recorded (for example, perhaps in a low scoring game in wet weather) a player's relative output is valued equivalent to that of another player in a match where more statistics are recorded (eg. perhapsa high scoring game).

I have added in dummy variables to my data set to account for the scaling in each individual match, however these will not be added in as linear factors but must multiply across all the other variables.

When I run this though I get a whole stack of interaction terms per game. What I really want though is for the estimate of the dummy variable to be constant, as the scaling needs to apply to all other variables in the same way, rather than coming out in the wash as different effects in different interaction terms.

Perhaps this is not a linear model now, and I need to look elsewhere, but my stats knowledge is only at an undergraduate level.

Cheers

Comment: This is not a linear model, what you want is really a multiplicative model. You could perhaps use a GLM (generalized Linear Model) with log link function. Then your extra multiplicative parameyter will be an extra game/sports(?)-dependent intercept, maybe given as an offset. Can you give a little more details, try to write down your model algebraically, and give a little part of your data matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - very helpful. A generalised model for a player's scoring in a game might be:

Points (Player A) = a1*X1A + a2*X2A + a2*X3A ... where X1, X2... are the match statistics for Player A.

However, the addition of points for all players is a constant. Therefore there is effectively a scaling term applied to all players, which is constant for a match but differs across matches.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - very helpful. A generalised model for a player's scoring in a game might be:

Player A: Points_A = a1*X1A + a2*X2A + a2*X3A ... where X1, X2... are the match statistics for Player A.

Player B: Points_B = a*X1B + a2*X2B + a3*X3B ...

However, the addition of points for all players is a constant. Therefore there is effectively a scaling term applied to all players, which is constant for a match but differs across matches.

Therefore:

Player A, Game I: Points_A_I = aI * (a1*X1A + a2*X2A + a2*X3A...)
Player F, Game IV: Points_F_IV = aIV * (a*X1F + a2*X2F + a3*X3F ...)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! But still, you write as if everybody knows about "fantasy sports" and "fanrasy sports scores".  Maybe everybody your age does ... I am probably older! So can you please explain (as an edit to original question) what these terms means, and hove that "fantasy score" is obtained?

Comment: I found this one:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy_baseball